# How can I add sitemap.xml to angularJS site?

Tags: angularjs, seo

I added sitemap.xml in app folder but how can I make it public so that the google webmaster tool can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From Google's *[Build and Submit a Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190&authuser=0)* Documentation:

> There are two different ways to make your sitemap available to Google:
>
> [Submit it to Google using the Search Console Sitemaps tool](https://search.google.com/search-console/sitemaps?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=183668)
>
> **OR**
>
> Insert
>   the following line anywhere in your robots.txt file, specifying the
>   path to your sitemap: `Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml`

Answer (score 0):

you can make it visible by storing it outside of your angular application. so simply put it into your main directory and link to it in webmaster tools: http://yourDomain.com/sitemap.xml

the yearofmoo article is helpful but in the end they also recommend using a sitemap along with their technique. **In your sitemap you should use full url paths to access a state.**

Answer (score 0):

Put your `sitemap.xml` file in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Put the Sitemap.xml in the Root directory of your website or WebApp.
just like http://example.com/sitemap.xml . In your case Disable the Angular.js Routing

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to generate sitemap online and download that Sitemap.XML file and give your developer. 
The developer set priority according to your website page and according to priority your sitemap URL crawl by Google Bot.