# How to add sitemap.xml in an angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, gruntjs, sitemap

I have created an angularjs app using [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack). Things are working good except one. I'm trying to add sitemap.xml to this app so that it can be indexed by search engines crawlers. Using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523274/how-can-i-add-sitemap-xml-to-angularjs-site), I created a sitemap.xml in my **client/** directory. It is working properly on Development Environment when I start my application using *grunt serve* but on Production, it's not working when I'm starting the app using *grunt serve:dist*. This is my robots.txt https://crowdvirality.com/robots.txt Whenever I try to access https://www.crowdvirality.com/sitemap-secure.xml or https://www.crowdvirality.com/sitemap.xml, it redirects me to https://www.crowdvirality.com/error page.

My app.js contains following rule:

> ```
>   .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
>     $urlRouterProvider
>       .otherwise('/error');
>   })
> ```

This same set up works on local dev environment but fails on prod. Can anyone give me some pointers where I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok its a common issue i think.

You are basically trying to serve a file instead of a route.

I was doing this the other day with a pdf

You have to create a route with a file extension in your route provider.

For example ...

```
.state('sitemap.xml', {url: '/sitemap.xml'})
```

the . in the state name is vital, this lets angular know you are serving a file and not a route

ATM because you do not have this state, you are falling back on your otherwise state

Comment: one quick doubt, if that is the case then how come it is serving robots.txt properly ? And adding this state is irrespective of the actual location of sitemap.xml, right ?

Comment: the url i believe points to the location of the doc, the state name is what goes in the browser url as usual. not sure why robots.txt is working properly.

Comment: Found the issue. My gruntfile was not copying xml files in dist/ directory. I added a rule for that and bingo. Everything is working properly. No need of adding these extra routes